# Sending Mail over proxy server

Tags: c#, email

I am using a LAN network, which uses a proxy server. In C#, I am trying to develop an application through which I can send E-mails. But from my network, I can't send mail due to this proxy issue. From any other network, not dependent on proxy server, there is no problem to send mail.

I typed in command prompt, `telnet smtp.gmail.com 25`

and it displays it can't connect to 'smtp.gmail.com'

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your proxy is explicitly denying the gmail.com domain (if its a corporate network then many do). Can you reach gmail.com in your browser (if you can't this may put up a nasty looking alert from your systems guys).

There are a couple of ways round this:

1. Get smtp.gmail.com, or port 25 to smtp.gmail.com, unblocked on the proxy.
2. Get an smtp relay put in place instaed of using smtp from gmail. There's some info on this [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above).

Either way, time to go and be nice to your sys admins!